# Generando archivo Excel desde una tabla PHP

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

que tal estoy generando el archivo Excel de una tabla de la base de datos en un sistema, el archivo se esta generando muy bien cuando son campos de texto pero cuando el campo esta llamando un id de otra tabla solo imprime el numero de id, lo que necesito y no he podido hacer es que me imprima en el documento al generarse el nombre dependiendo el id, por ejemplo tengo dos campos por ahora uno es status_id y el otro es user_id, este caso el estatus es pendiente pero tiene el id 1 y el usuario que lo creo aqui es el admin y es el 1 entonces el codigo del archivo es el siguiente

```html
<?php

/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
include "../core/autoload.php";

include "../core/app/model/StatusData.php";
include "../core/app/model/UserData.php";

/** Include PHPExcel */
require "../core/controller/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php";



if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli')
    die('Este ejemplo sólo se puede ejecutar desde un navegador Web');

/** Incluye PHPExcel */

// Crear nuevo objeto PHPExcel
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$users = UserData::getAll();
// Propiedades del documento
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Angellomix")
                             ->setLastModifiedBy("Angellomix")
                             ->setTitle("Office")
                             ->setSubject("Office")
                             ->setDescription("Documento de Office XLSX, generado usando clases de PHP.")
                             ->setKeywords("office openxml php")
                             ->setCategory("Archivo de tickets");



// Combino las celdas desde A1 hasta E1
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->mergeCells('A1:F1');

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A1', 'TICKETS')       
            ->setCellValue('A2', 'TÍTULO')
            ->setCellValue('B2', 'DESCRIPCIÓN')
            ->setCellValue('C2', 'USUARIO')
            ->setCellValue('D2', 'ESTATUS')
            ->setCellValue('E2', 'FECHA')
            ->setCellValue('F2', 'SOLUCIÓN');
            
// Fuente de la primera fila en negrita
$boldArray = array('font' => array('bold' => true,),'alignment' => array('horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER));

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:f2')->applyFromArray($boldArray);      

    
            
//Ancho de las columnas
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(40);  
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(50);  
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setWidth(15);  
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('D')->setWidth(20);  
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('E')->setWidth(20);          
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('F')->setWidth(80);
/*Extraer datos de MYSQL*/
    # conectare la base de datos
    $con=@mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'tiketonline');
    if(!$con){
        die("imposible conectarse: ".mysqli_error($con));
    }
    if (@mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        die("Connect failed: ".mysqli_connect_errno()." : ". mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    $sql="SELECT * FROM ticket";
    $query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $cel=3;//Numero de fila donde empezara a crear  el reporte
    
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $titl=$row['title'];
        $descriptio=$row['description'];
        $user_i=$row['user_id'];
        $project_i=$row['status_id'];
        $fecha=$row['created_at'];
        $solucion=$row['solution'];
        
            $a="A".$cel;
            $b="B".$cel;
            $c="C".$cel;
            $d="D".$cel;
            $e="E".$cel;
            $f="F".$cel;

            // Agregar datos
            foreach($users as $user){
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue($a, $titl)
            ->setCellValue($b, $descriptio)
            ->setCellValue($c, $user_i)
            ->setCellValue($d, $project_i)
            ->setCellValue($e, $fecha)
            ->setCellValue($f, $solucion);
            
    $cel+=1;
    }
}
/*Fin extracion de datos MYSQL*/


// Cambiar el nombre de hoja de cálculo
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Reporte de TICKETS');


// Establecer índice de hoja activa a la primera hoja , por lo que Excel abre esto como la primera hoja
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);


// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel2007)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="tickets-'.time().'.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
// If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

// If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
?>
```

al dar clic en el botón se imprime el siguiente documento, estoy marcando con amarillo donde el campo solo imprime el id que es lo que estoy enviando pero quisiera que se imprima el name del id podrían ayudarme a como puedo hacerlo que codigo implementar e robado varios pero no logro hacerlo por su ayuda gracias les leo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la tabla tickets

```html
create table ticket(
    id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    title varchar(100),
    description text,
    updated_at datetime,
    created_at datetime,
    fecha datetime,
    kind_id int,
    user_id int not null,
    asigned_id int,
    project_id int,
    category_id int,
    fuente_id int,
    subsoport_id int,
    cateam_id int,
    subcontpaq_id int,
    solution varchar(300),
    priority_id int not null default 1,
    foreign key (priority_id) references priority(id),
    status_id int not null default 1,
    foreign key (status_id) references status(id),
    foreign key (user_id) references user(id),
    foreign key (kind_id) references kind(id),
    foreign key (category_id) references category(id),
    foreign key (project_id) references project(id),
    foreign key (fuente_id) references fuente(id),
    foreign key (subsoport_id) references subsoport(id),
    foreign key (cateam_id) references cateam(id),
    foreign key (subcontpaq_id) references subcontpaq(id)
);
```

y estos son los campos que se muestran al guardar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la tabla estatus se mira asi

```html
create table status (
    id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(100)
);
```

al igual que la de prioridad que es otro capo que agregare

```html
create table priority (
    id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(100)
);
```

Comment: Claro pero si te das cuenta estas imprimiendo el ID porque estas trayendo el ID

Comment: Tienes que buscar el nombre por el id, puedes mostrarnos que trae el query **SELECT * FROM ticket**

Comment: @JosueVargas en la tabla ticket los campos se guardan solo los id no los nombre, agrego en el final de este la tabla ticket

Comment: Donde Guardas los nombres? puedes mostrarnos la tabla?

Comment: por ejemplo la de status seria asi las demas es similar con esepcion de la de usuario que tiene mas campos;   create table status (
 id int not null auto_increment primary key,
 name varchar(100)
);

Comment: Tenés que hacer un **join** de la tabla donde guardas el **id** a la tabla usuarios, y con el campo que dice **estatus** puedes hacer uso de un  **case** `CASE WHEN ESTATUS = 1 THEN 'ACTIVO' ELSE 'INACTIVO' END AS ESTATUS`

Comment: Bien si no sabes tanto de sql coloca tu query aqui http://sqlfiddle.com/ y nos das link asi te ayudamos mejor

Answer (score 0):

Pues eñ tema esta en la query bro, solo tienes que traerte ya sea la descripcion de tu id o ponerlo por case en la siguiente forma

```
<?php
     $sql="SELECT 
    case when (id=1) -- pones la condicion
    then 'Estatus activo' -- lo que quieres que pase cuando se cumpla
     when (id=2) then 'Siguiente estatus'
    end as Estatus -- aqui nombras el campo como quieres traerlo al excel 
    when FROM ticket";
?>
```

ahora tambien lo puedes hacer esto con php pero yo en lo personal te sugiero que lo cambies desde la query ya que entre mas procesos le des a php que procese mas lento se vuelve, y sql es un excelente motor de base de datos que puede ahorrarte mucho y ser mucho mas eficaz

Comment: Podrías ayudarme a como implementarlo en el código ya con la condición, pensando en el ejemplo que me comentas que cuando sea id 1 se envié en Enviado, 2 en Proceso y 3 Terminado. esos serian los campos que se verían dependiendo el id en el archivo excel

Comment: SELECT 
  title
  description
  user_id
  case when (status_id=1) then 'Enviado'
   when (status_id=2) then 'En proceso'
    when (status_id=3) then 'Terminado'
  end as status_id,
  created_at
  solution
  FROM ticket

Comment: me falto mandar las comas pero espero te sirva

Comment: lo probare, muchas gracias por el tiempo